# My doOnComplete is called before .Map finsihes

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-android

I have a problem with kotlin observables, I have searched through internet and stackoverflow but I think I am missing something in concepts. I have dashboardRepository which has method called getCallsCountForWeek, this basically returns flowable list for last 7 days and now I need to iterate through all flowables and then update my graph with count of calls user made for that day. Here is my code

```
fun getCallsCountForWeek(calendar: Calendar) : List<Flowable<Float>> {

    val result = ArrayList<Flowable<Float>>()

    for(index  in 0..6) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -index)
        result.add(dashbordDao.getCallsCountForDay(customSharedPreferences.getUser()?.id!!, CustomDateTimeUtil.getStartOfDay(calendar), CustomDateTimeUtil.getEndOfDay(calendar)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
    }

    return result
}


        Observable.fromArray(dashboardRepository
        .getCallsCountForWeek(calendar). map {
        items -> kotlin.run {
            items.forEach {
                it.subscribe({
                    Log.e("Result", " Count: " + it)
                },{
                    Log.e("Error", "" + it)
                })
            }
        }
    }.doOnComplete {
        //We will do this when it is completed
        Log.e("Result", "Completed")
    }.doFinally {
        Log.e("Result", "Finally")
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe()
```

The problem is that doFinally and doOnComplete are called before map completes its iteration through all the flowables. I tried to use .zip for flowables but apparently could not make it work too.

According to other posts on stack overflow, doOnComplete is called when subscription is successful but I want that to happen after everything is done inside .map.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flatMap` or `flatMapIterable` instead of `map` and have only one `subscribe` call

```
 Observable.fromArray(dashboardRepository
    .getCallsCountForWeek(calendar)
    .flatMapIterable { it }  // iterate over list
    .flatMap { it }  // use flowables from list
    .doOnNext { /* do something with every item */ }
    .doOnComplete {
        //We will do this when it is completed
        Log.e("Result", "Completed")
    }
    .doFinally {
        Log.e("Result", "Finally")
   
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .ignoreElements () // if you already handled everything in the doOnNext
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: thanks, I will give it a shot now and be right back.

Comment: I made bit of change but this pointed me in right direction. I will add the solution now to my question so that someone may find it useful.
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into answer from Eugene Popovich. I was pointed into right direction and then I did the following and it worked.

So, first thing, I modified my function to return list of Single Observable instead of Flowable as that any who made ore sense. Once done I did following as suggested by Eugene but just using flatMapSingle instead of flatMap.

```
    Observable.fromArray(dashboardRepository.getCallsCountForWeek(calendar))
        .flatMapIterable { it }  // iterate over list
        .flatMapSingle {
                it
        }
        .doOnNext {
            barEtries.add( BarEntry(index++, it))
        }
        .doOnComplete {
            //We will do this when it is completed
            Log.e("Result", "Completed "+barEtries)
            setBarChartData()
        }
        .doFinally {
            Log.e("Result", "Finally")

        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .ignoreElements () // if you already handled everything in the doOnNext
        .subscribe()
```

The change in getCallsCountForWeek was as below, basically just used single instead of Flowable because it made more sense and flatMapSingle provided out of the box resolution without calling even subscribe.

```
fun getCallsCountForWeek(calendar: Calendar) : ArrayList<Single<Float>> {

  val result = ArrayList<Single<Float>>()

   for(index  in 0..6) {
      calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -index)
    result.add(dashbordDao.getCallsCountForDay(customSharedPreferences.getUser()?.id!!, CustomDateTimeUtil.getStartOfDay(calendar), CustomDateTimeUtil.getEndOfDay(calendar)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
}

    return result
}
```